# Save Background-Image in Session in Drupal

Tags: php, css, drupal

I have a website and I want to randomly pick a background-image for the page. This image should be saved in a session variable until the browser is closed. At the moment every time the page refreshes the random function is called again and again, but it should stay in the session. So how can I save a background-image into the Browser Session with drupal or generally php which stays there until browser closes?

Here the code which calls at every page load the random function.

```
<div id="page" style="background: url('/sites/all/themes/klickers/css/images/bgtop-0<?php    echo rand(1, 4); ?>.jpg') no-repeat 50% 0 #000000;" class="<?php print $classes; ?>">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would do it

```
<?php
session_set_cookie_params(0); // this will ensure your session destroys when browser is closed
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['bgImage'])) {
$bgImage = rand(1, 4);
$_SESSION['bgImage'] = $bgImage;
} 
?>
<div id="page" style="background: url('/sites/all/themes/klickers/css/images/bgtop-0<?php    echo $_SESSION['bgImage']; ?>.jpg') no-repeat 50% 0 #000000;" class="<?php print $classes; ?>">
```

**EDITED**

added `session_set_cookie_params(0);`

Comment: Yes that works perfect. It does work if I put session_set_cookie_params(0) into the if clause. Thanks very much. My code is updated on the mainpost.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

session_start(); //call this before doing anything else
if (isset($_SESSION['bgimage'])) {
    $bgimage = $_SESSION['bgimage'];
}
else {
    $bgimage = mt_rand(1,4); //mt_rand() is the better rand()
    $_SESSION['bgimage'] = $bgimage;
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
...
<div id="page" style="background: url('/sites/all/themes/klickers/css/images/bgtop-0<?php echo $bgimage ?>.jpg') no-repeat 50% 0 #000000;" class="<?php print $classes; ?>">
```

Comment: I tried your code but it first says: "Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in include()". Also tried without session_start but it does not save it. Drupal needs there somthing other, but php overall your code works, but sadly not in drupal.

Comment: You need to echo `$_SESSION['bgimage']` in your image tag not `$bgimage`